# SAS: Separate date_from & date_to into separate lines

Tags: date, sas

I've got an example like this:

```
data date_table;
stop;
    length id $32.;
    length name $32.;
    length date_from date_to 8.;
    format date_from date_to datetime19.;
run;


proc sql;

insert into date_table 
    values ('1', 'Mark', '13Jun2019 08:39:00'dt, '13Jun2019 11:39:00'dt)
    values ('2', 'Bart', '13Jun2019 13:39:00'dt, '13Jun2019 17:39:00'dt);

quit;
```

[image]

I need some smart join (maybe with separate hour mapping table) to achieve something like this:

[image]

What I've been trying now was using mapping table

[image]

and join like:

```
proc sql;

create table testing as 
select t1.id,
        t1.name,
        t1.date_from,
        t1.date_to

from DATE_TABLE t1 inner join 
     WORK.CAL_TIME t2 on t1.date_from >= t2.Time and 
                         t1.date_to <= t2.Time;

quit;
```

But of course the result is empty table because date dpoens't want t join. I might cut date_from and date_to to full hours but still such a join doens't work.

Help.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compare datetime values (number of seconds since 1960) with time values (number of seconds since midnight).  Perhaps you just need to use the `timepart()` function on your datetime values to pull of just the time of day part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are comparing apples (DATETIME) with oranges (TIME).  The order of magnitude of those numbers are totally different.

```
684   data _null_;
685
686   dt = '13Jun2019 08:39:00'dt ;
687   tm = '08:00't ;
688   put (dt tm) (=comma20.);
689   run;

dt=1,876,034,340 tm=28,800
```

You probably just want to compare the time of day part of your datetime values to your time values.  Also round your start times down and your end times up to the hour.

```
data date_table;
  length id name $32 date_from date_to 8;
  format date_from date_to datetime19.;
  input id name (date:) (:datetime.);
cards;
1 Mark 13Jun2019:08:39:00 13Jun2019:11:39:00
2 Bart 13Jun2019:13:39:00 13Jun2019:17:39:00
;
data cal_time;
 do time='08:00't to '21:00't by '01:00't ;
   output;
 end;
 format time time5.;
run;

proc sql;
create table testing as 
select t1.id
     , t1.name
     , max(t1.date_from,dhms(datepart(t1.date_from),0,0,t2.time))
        as datetime_from format=datetime19.
     , min(t1.date_to,dhms(datepart(t1.date_to),0,0,t2.time+'01:00't))
        as datetime_to format=datetime19.
     , t2.time
from DATE_TABLE t1 
inner join WORK.CAL_TIME t2 
  on t2.time between intnx('hour',timepart(t1.date_from),0,'b')
                 and intnx('hour',timepart(t1.date_to),0,'e')
;

quit;
```

Result

```
Obs    id    name          datetime_from            datetime_to     time

 1     1     Mark     13JUN2019:08:39:00     13JUN2019:09:00:00     8:00
 2     1     Mark     13JUN2019:09:00:00     13JUN2019:10:00:00     9:00
 3     1     Mark     13JUN2019:10:00:00     13JUN2019:11:00:00    10:00
 4     1     Mark     13JUN2019:11:00:00     13JUN2019:11:39:00    11:00
 5     2     Bart     13JUN2019:13:39:00     13JUN2019:14:00:00    13:00
 6     2     Bart     13JUN2019:14:00:00     13JUN2019:15:00:00    14:00
 7     2     Bart     13JUN2019:15:00:00     13JUN2019:16:00:00    15:00
 8     2     Bart     13JUN2019:16:00:00     13JUN2019:17:00:00    16:00
 9     2     Bart     13JUN2019:17:00:00     13JUN2019:17:39:00    17:00
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your oslution. WORKS GREAT. And I learnt somehting new about "between join". Regarding datetiem and date, that's on me - when I was preparing example to recreate real-world problem I did over look it.